# Can't connect local database. Sequel Pro encountered an unexpected error

Tags: mysql, macos, sequelpro

Sequel Pro 1.1.2 + MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 + MySQL 8.0.16 (Homebrew) have a problem when trying to connect to local (and ONLY local) databases. It pops up a feedback dialog and a never ending progress bar. There is no problem when working with remote databases.

There is a [bug report in their Github project page](https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3104), but it looks like they closed it for being a duplicate... and closed the duplicate as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Sequel Ace](https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace), an active and amazing working fork with the same UI/UX of the legacy Sequel Pro

Answer (score 5):

The nightly builds seem to be ok. download [here](https://sequelpro.com/test-builds)

Comment: With that version I can't browse any table from `local.information_schema`, I have to even force stop the app...

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same issue, so this version works fine for me. You can download this zip. [Click here to download Sequel Pro](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17v7AkYD8h3DipgKIr7nASH8zju5OlhpR?usp=sharing)